# Batch file help (skipping part of it if something is running)

Tags: batch-file

My program I am building is a backup type of program and sometimes I would like to have the ability to reset my service which runs it, sometimes the service stops sending data and I have found simply restarting the service helps.

Currently the batch file resets the service every hour

I would like to know how I can make my batch file check if a program is running and if so, to skip  this line

net stop "my service" && net start "my service"

The Program that I am wanting to see if it's running is a file service which has multiple threads.
myprogram_thread01.exe
myprogram_thread02.exe
myprogram_thread03.exe
so I am wanting to use a Wildcard character *
eg: myprogram_thread*

```
@echo off
:loop
net stop "my service" && net start "my service"
timeout /t 3600
goto loop
```

Thank you.

Comment: When a program has different threads, this does not mean that there are different executables, there are just different threads for one and the same executable.

Comment: Don't use `net.exe stop …` and `net.exe start …` for your services use `sc.exe stop …` and `sc.exe start …` instead. If you read its usage information, _(`sc /?` entered at the Command Prompt)_, you should note that there are other things it can do too. You'll find that its `query` option, possibly with `type= service`, may be useful in determining the status of your service, and help to trigger an action based upon that result! The question has definitley been asked and answered before on this site, so after reading the usage information, please use the search facility at the top of the page.